# PHP JQuery fetching contents from download dialog

Tags: php, jquery, casperjs

When I go to a URL, the page prompts me to download the file. But using `CURL` or `file_get_contents`, it is not returning the content of that download file.

Do we have any PHP/jQuery code to run the link and fetch the contents that that will be downloaded when hitting the save/open button?

Comment: Try this, look like you are fetching a redirect link https://evertpot.com/curl-redirect-requestbody/

Comment: Thanks!! But that didn't work

Comment: @LeoAnand what **Đào Minh Hạt** suggested is most likely the solution to your problem. The page you have has a location header inside its response. Update your question and include the page URL and the code you're trying to download the file with.